# How to force TortoiseGit to NOT show push all branches windows all time?

Tags: tortoisegit

Previously when I clicking button "Commit and push" in tortoise git, it showed "push all branches" window only when I had a new branch. After update, this window will be shown every time after clicking "Common & Push".

How to skip this window?

Comment: TortoiseGit remembers the last selected entry on the push dialog. If the dialog always appears when you click on push&commit then your local branch doesn’t seem to have a remote tracking branch set up.

Comment: for a long time it worked good. but after changing origin (I think) it asks everytime

Answer (score 0):

When pushing new branch, tortoise git shows 2 checkes at the end of window, with labels:
[image: when pushing new branch]

- Always push to the selected remote archive for this local branch
- Always push to the selected remote branch for this local branch

Tick them or in branch browser window (can be reached from switch/checkout branch command or other places) select command `select tracked branch`
[image: select tracked branch]